# Keras TLSTM ext Classification differing train and test shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a text classification problem in which I am feeding GloVe embeddings into an LSTM network. I have preprocessed the text and perform the following below:

```
max_features = 300 
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train['text'].values)
train_f = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train['text'].values)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index #used for word embeddings
train_f = pad_sequences(train_f)
```

The shape of train_f is: (25000, 1225). I then performed the same on the test set:

```
max_features = 300 
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(test['text'].values)
test_f = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test['text'].values)
test_f = pad_sequences(test_f)
```

This resulted in a test shape of: (25000, 1223). When going ahead and loaded the embeddings in and fit the network. I am unable to predict on the testing set as I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_2_input to have shape (1225,) but got array with shape (1223,)
```

I cannot seem to spot my mistake. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have an error on the code of your test set :

```
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(test['text'].values)
test_f = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train['text'].values)
```

should be :

```
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(test['text'].values)
test_f = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test['text'].values)
```

#### Edit

It's looks like you just don't have the same test and train shape before your tokenize it.

Check the shape of your `test['text']` and `train['text']`

Comment: Good catch! That was actually a typo on my end pasting it into Stack Over Flow.

Comment: In regards to your edit, how can I go about ensuring the test and train shape is the same before tokenizing? They only contain text.